# Select Document in Array by Member

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo collection called `Conversations` with a schema like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "string",
    "participants" : [ "strings", "..." ],
    "messages" : [
        {
            "_id" : "string",
            "message" : "contents of the message",
            "sent" : "date sent",
            "read" : false
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

With a `Conversations._id` value and a `Conversations.messages[?]._id` value, I need to be able to update that message's `read` field. The `Conversations.messages._id` values are unique across all message documents.

I've been doing some research, and I'm lead to believe that I should be using some type of aggregation? Am I on the right track with this?

Comment: Aggregation is costly.. u can try distinct as Conversations.messages._id is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating Mongo nested array fields check this [mongo update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)
below query will update `messages.read`

```
db.converstaion.update({"_id" :"youstringId","messages":{"$elemMatch":{"_id":"msg string id"}}},
                       {"$set":{"messages.$.read":true}})
```